Prove that the two line segments are equal
Segment $\overline{AP}$ and segment $\overline{BC}$ bisect each other. Also segments $\overline{AC}$ and $\overline{BQ}$ bisect each other. Prove that $PC = QC$. I have no idea how to even start with this one, since normally when trying to prove two segments have the same length, I'd try to look for congruent triangles, but I can't find any in here that are related to the two line segments. I would like some help!

Here is a picture of the problem.

Since $BC$ and $AP$ bisect each other, it's easy to show that $PC=AB$. Similarly $QC=AB$. Therefore $QC=PC$.
You congruent triangles are the pairs $\triangle M1CP$ and $\triangle M1BA$ for the first case, and $\triangle M2QC$ and $\triangle M2BA$ for the second.

Hint: Let M be the midpoint of AP/BC and N be the midpoint of AC/BQ. Then show that |CQ| and |PC| are both twice |MN|. Is that sufficient for you to complete the proof?
You could also use a vector method: the two segments do not just have the same length; in fact vector PC = vector CQ = twice vector MN.
